For $\mathbb R^n \times Q \cong \mathbb R^m \times Q $ must $n = m$? ($Q$ is the Hilbert cube)
There are several theorems describing the topology on hyperspaces of convex subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ under the Hausdorff metric. For example Antonyan and Jonard-Pérez prove the space of compact convex sets with interior is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n(n+3)/2} \times Q$ for $Q$ the Hilbert cube. The same authors and Juárez-Ordóñez later proved that the space of compact convex sets of constant width $1$ say, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n\times Q$.
I wonder is it easy to show the exponent is well-defined? Meaning if $\mathbb R^n \times Q$ and $\mathbb R^m \times Q $ are homeomorphic, must we have $n = m$?

Let $P_n$ be the condition, for a topological space $X$: for every compact subset $Y\subset X$, there exists a compact subset $Z$ containing $Y$ such that $\pi_i(X-Z)$ is trivial for all $i\le n$. Then $Q\times\mathbf{R}^n$ satisfies $P_{n-2}$ but not $P_{n-1}$ (agreeing that $P_{-1}$ holds for every space).

Alternatively cohomology with compact support does the job.

Note that $\mathbb{R}^n\times Q$ is proper homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If they were homeomorphic, we would obtain a proper homotopy equivalence between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Using homotopy groups at infinity (as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316843/is-mathbbrn-properly-homotopy-equivalent-to-mathbbrm-if-n-neq-m), this can only happen for $m=n$.
